# Java Store Register Application Navigational Mechanics

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, navigation

I am trying to make a Store Register application in Java (for fun), but I am new to the language and am not exactly sure how to proceed from where I am. Currently, I successfully created a login system so when I hit login, the user login works. Now, I want to make it so that when I click login, it takes me to a menu of options. I do NOT want to open a new JFrame when the user clicks login, but instead, I want everything to happen in one a single JFrame. Also, I do not want you guys to do it for me, but i want to know how to approach this.

Here is the code I have for reference:

```
package schoolstoreregister;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SchoolStoreRegister extends JFrame {

        //declaring our swing components
    JLabel l_name,l_pass;
    JTextField t_name;
    JPasswordField t_pass;     //A special JTextField but hides input text
    JButton button;
    Container c;
    boolean checkLogin = false;

    //a inner class to handling ActionEvents
    handler handle;

    //a separate class for processing database connection and authentication
    database db;    

    SchoolStoreRegister()
    {
        super("School Store Register");

        c=getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
        int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();

        //extra classes
        db=new database();
            handle =new handler();

                //swing components
        //l_name=new JLabel("Username");
        l_pass=new JLabel("Password");
        //t_name=new JTextField(10);
        t_pass=new JPasswordField(10);
        button=new JButton("Login");

        //adding actionlistener to the button
        button.addActionListener(handle);

        //add to contaienr
       // c.add(l_name);
        //c.add(t_name);
        c.add(l_pass);
        c.add(t_pass);
        c.add(button);
        //visual
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(width,height);

    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            SchoolStoreRegister sample=new SchoolStoreRegister();
    }

    class handler implements ActionListener        //This is triggered whenever the user clicks the login button
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) //checks if the button clicked
        {
            if(ae.getSource()==button)
            {
                char[] temp_pwd=t_pass.getPassword();
                String convert = t_pass.getText();
                int passID = Integer.parseInt(convert);

                //The entered username and password are sent via "checkLogin()" which return boolean
                if(db.checkLogin(passID))
                {
                    //a pop-up box
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have logged in successfully","Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    checkLogin = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //a pop-up box
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login failed!","Failed!!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    checkLogin = false;
                }
            }//if
        }//method

    }//inner class
}
```

Comment: Embrace common [coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a `CardLayout` to swap out one panel (login screen) for another (main screen) in your `JFrame`.